# htaccess redirect for everything but files/directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, litespeed

I am trying to create a rewrite rule that accomplishes two things:

1. Redirect `(www.)?domain.com` to `log.domain.com`
2. Let any other directory or file request on domain.com through without redirection

This not an Apache server (it's LiteSpeed), but supposedly it supports `.htaccess` files wholly.

This was my shot at the rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://log.domain.com/
```

What's happening is that if I request a specific file (like dir/index.php) it's let through, but directory requests are still redirected to log.domain.com.  I thought the `$` of the second RewriteCond would keep this from happening, but that seems to not be the case.

EDIT: Just for archival purposes my intention was not to redirect any nonexistent directories/files to the log.domain.com since users should never have to do that.  This made the criteria a lot simpler for the rule, which chaos and gumbo both arrived at with their first rules below.  Thanks again!

Comment: You should have said that you only want the URL path “/” to be redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://log.domain.com/
```

Comment: This works for letting directories or files through, but it now stopped redirecting (www.)?domain.com to log.domain.com.

Comment: REQUEST_FILENAME is never just “/”. (Except you use something like this: “RewriteRule ^ /”)

Comment: The revised rule didn't do the trick either--still fails to redirect to log.domain.com.

Comment: Instead of trying to handle the exceptions, would it make more sense to ONLY redirect if the user requests exactly (www.)?domain.com(/)? and nothing else?  I'm not sure how to do that, but that seems like it might be an easier approach.

Comment: I thought we were going through all this because OP wanted to also redirect all 404s.

Comment: @chaos that didn't seem to work either, sorry.

The purpose of this rewrite is to route all visitors to log.domain.com, which is a custom A record that points to my tumblr.com blog.  I still use the webserver for file storage, so I need to be able to supply directories/files and not be redirected.

Comment: Okay, had a little thought.  If this one doesn't work, then it's brute force time.

Comment: Haha yeah that one failed to redirect as well.  I'm okay with brute force though. =)

Comment: Okay, there's the brute force.  Not real different from Gumbo's.  One of them's bound to work...

Comment: Oddly enough, just the first rule seems to work for everything.  Directories/Files go through, and domain.com requests are routed to log.domain.com

Comment: ... oh.  I could've sworn you wanted to reroute stuff like www.domain.com/thisdoesnotexist.  Well, okay then, I'll just chop out the cruft. :)

Comment: doh no sorry--I don't anticipate needing to do that for 404 purposes since nobody by myself should be using the domain for anything other than getting redirected to my blog. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# skip the next rule if host is not example.com or www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [S]

# redirect if requested URI does not match a regular file or directory
# or if the requested URI path is just "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
RewriteRule ^ http://log.example.com/
```

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, I believe your first rule would do the trick as well.